# View ILoger.LogDebug history

Tags: c#, logging

How can I view the history of logs written by the ILoger.LogDebug and ILoger.LogError methods?
I am new to these methods and no matter how hard I tried I did not understand how to do it!

Comment: Did you try to implement the Interface in a class of your own, register your `Ilogger` and save all incoming calls to a List?